# Every orthogonal operator is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Answer is false and the rotation is a counterexample.
But I can't understand well.
Let $A=\begin {pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ then it is rotation and also orthogonal operator. I think it can be diagonalizable by eigenvalue $i,-i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They (implicitly) meant "diagonalizable *over the reals*", and making a diagonal matrix whose entries are $i$ and $-i$ are not allowed when we are requiring all of our matrices' entries be real numbers. From [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable):

> In general, a rotation matrix is not diagonalizable over the reals, but all rotation matrices are diagonalizable over the complex field.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of "diagonalizability" highly depends on the ground field. If we consider the rotation 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
as an operator $A \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, then it is not diagonalizable, as its characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(t) = t^2 + 1$ does not have any roots over $\mathbb R$.

If we consider $A \colon \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2$, then $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\pm i$.

Answer (score -1):

You should have been right that it is diagonalizable because there exists $X$ s.t. $A = X\Lambda X^{-1}$. There are also non-diagonalizable matrices that always have the form $A = XJX^{-1}$, where $J$ is the Jordan matrix of $A$.

Comment: As both martini's answer and my answer point out, the notion of "diagonalizable" depends on what field one is working over. The matrix is not diagonalizable over the real numbers.

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question: since orthogonal matrices are normal their Jordan forms are always diagonal.  In other words this matrix is still not "Jordanable" over the reals.

Comment: But the question didn't mention anything about the scalar field. Then I assume that it is $\mathbb{C}$. What would be the resolvent set, if complex numbers weren't accepted?